# Angular 2, how to use setTimeout?

Tags: angular

In a login page, I have this function when they submit the page:

```
checkLogin(){
    this.x_userS.getLogin(this.x_userO.login_name, this.x_userO.pwd_plain).then(response => this.x_userO=response);
    (function(){
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (this.x_userO.login_status == "1") {
                this.x_companyS.getCompanyByUser(this.x_userO.user_id).then(response => this.x_companyO=response);
                (function(){setTimeout(() => {
                    this.x_userS.setUser(this.x_userO);
                    this.x_companyS.setCompany(this.x_companyO);
                    this.router.navigate(['HomePage']);
                }, 2000);
            })();
            }
            else {
                window.alert("oops");
            }
        }, 2000);
    })();
}
```

where x_userS is the login service and x_userO is the user object. I'm trying to give the promises two seconds to return the data before processing it. Without the setTimeout, it does not return it in time.

I tried removing everything except the alert and verified it happened after two seconds. However, it doesn't recognize any of the other stuff inside function(){} so I believe I need to pass all my services and objects in.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I believe you use $timeout

Comment: $timeout is only for Angular 1; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40402767/132374

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you use `function()`, then `this.` won't point to variables in your class.
Use `() =>` instead everywhere.

The `(function(){ ... })()` around `setTimeout()` seems to be redundant anyway.

Comment: thanks, I removed the function() part and it works fine with `this`. I was following an example and he used function(j) to pass in a number j, I thought if I didn't want to pass anything in I would just leave function as ().

Comment: Yep arrow functions give you the right this context for this problem.  Thanks!