# Angular2: setTimeout only called once

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, settimeout

I'm implementing functionality in Angular2 that requires the use of `setTimeout`.

My code:

```
  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.authenticate_loop();
  }

  private authenticate_loop() {
    setTimeout (() => {
      console.log("Hello from setTimeout");
    }, 500)
  }
```

`setTimeout` is started by `ngAfterViewInit` but the loop is only executed once, eg. "Hello fromsetTimeout" is only printed once.

**Question:** How can I change the code to make the setTimeout work?

Comment: Because timeout only runs once...

Comment: you can see  http://blog.neilni.com/2016/03/27/settimeout-in-angular-2/

Comment: Edit your question to angular 1 instead of angular 2, you have accepted an answer that uses angular 1 services.

Comment: True, did not notice. Correct answer has now been accepted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 private authenticate_loop() {
    setInterval (() => {
      console.log("Hello from setInterval");
    }, 500)
 }
```

`setTimeout` will run just one time, unless you create another `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** So to be more specific for the different angular versions:

In **Angular2** you are not required to use $timeout / $interval any more. So for the question here **setInterval** is the correct solution.

For any one interested in the original response (targeted to Angular1) read the following:

Use [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) inside an angular.js application.

And if you want to use setTimeout somewhere else inside an angular.js application you should better use the [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service.

**$timeout** and **$interval** have the advantage, that they keep your scope updated, which setTimeout / setInterval do not.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but the examples used are angular1.