# Angular2 Template Not updating

Tags: angular, typescript, electron

I'm updating the message of a component after 3 seconds, yet it doesn't update in the template. I've tried installing angular2-polyfills (some people said to try that), I've tried

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef)
{ ....
    this.cd.markForCheck();
  ....
}
```

but nothing seems to work. Here's the full component:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, ChangeDetectorRef } from 
'@angular/core';

//Defines a standard component
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './App.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
message: String = "hello"; //Message im trying to update

 //Just to try ChangeDetectorRef...
 constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef)
 {
    //Timer that sets the message to '"HELLOWITHOUTWORLD" after 3 seconds
    window.setTimeout(function () { 
        this.message = "HELLOWITHOUTWORLD"; 
        console.log("changed it " + this.message); 
    }, 3000);
    //I ALSO TRIED DOING "this.zone.run" but kept getting zone is undefined
    //window.setTimeout(function () { this.zone.run(() => { this.message = "HELLOWITHOUTWORLD"; console.log("changed it"); }); }, 3000);

    //Some sites said that this would update the template...
    this.cd.markForCheck();
 }
}
```

and the HTML:

```
{{message}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar question here: [Angular 2, how to use setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38258655/angular-2-how-to-use-settimeout)

Tried it out in a simple [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mebrb8JS2lk318nHSCJF) and the solution is to change `function() { /* ... */ }` to an arrow function `() => { /* ... */ }`. These arrow functions will properly set the context of your block.

Your problem was that `this` inside the `function()` is an isolated scope and not your class as you were expecting. For change detection angular2 and above is very intuitive compared to angularjs : it does not work with a digest cycle anymore and will rarely require your input.

If you have prior JS experience you can imagine `() => {}` as

```
var _this = this;
function () {
  var this = _this;
  /* code */
}
```